Join attributes by location with condition
I have a point layer with observations of different bird species (layer_obs) and a polygon layer with the defined territory of these bird species based on the field observations (layer_terr). Each of these territories has an ID (terr_id field).
This ID is not assigned to points in layer_obs, but I need to know which observation belongs to which territory. Unfortunately, I cannot simply join an attribute by location because territories of different species can overlap and the point could be inside multiple polygons.

Both layers contain a field "bird_sp" which could be used as a condition. The idea is that if a point in layer_obs is inside a polygon in layer_terr AND the bird_sp value in layer_obs matches the bird_sp value in layer_terr THEN I want to add the terr_id value to the point in layer_obs. Multiples points may belong to one single territory but not vice versa.

Is there a way to include this condition in the join by location algorithm?

ProcessX Plug-In has an algorithm "Join attributes by nearest with condition". You could set the max-distance to 0.000000001 if that fulfills your need.

@MrXsquared thanks for your suggestion! I tried the algorithm but maybe I did something wrong. I put layer_obs as source and layer_terr as join layer, then terr_ID as join field and distance to 0.0...1. In the advanced parameters I selected bird_sp = bird_sp but the output layer has nothing in the new joined field. Could you pleas tell me how should I adapt the parameters?

You can use an Field Calculator expression on your point layer with a filter to ensure the bird_sp of the point is the same as the bird_sp of the territory, like so:
overlay_within(                                          -- returns an array of features that the current point feature is within
    'layer_terr',                                        -- the layer of interest from which the features are returned
    "terr_id",                                           -- the attribute of interest in layer_terr
    filter:= "bird_sp" = attribute(@feature, 'bird_sp')  -- "bird_sp" is retrieved from layer_terr. @feature is the current *point* feature being evaluated and its `bird_sp` is retrieved using the `attribute` function.
)[0]

Note:
Pay attention to the quotes in the filter line. Double quote " denotes an attribute value, whereas single quote ' denotes a field name (and is passed as a string to the attribute function.

You could aggregate the terr_id for each species using an expression:
aggregate('territories','concatenate',terr_id,intersects($geometry,geometry(@parent)),', ')
Now I understand what you want as desired output. You can add a join (right click > Preferences > Joins) and use bird_spec as field for joining. But this only works if bird_sp is unique because if it is not, you can not solve the case for points that lie within several territories.

My solutions are not particularly clever. Depending on the amount of species you have:
Not 100% that this will work as intended: Using the  next to the input and comparison layer you can access the feature filter.  Here you can enter the bird species you are trying to add. You can apply this filter for both layers. You should also specify what should happen if they can´t be joined. Probably easiest to run as batch process.
Alternatively: Select one species at a time based on your condition and then run the algorithm only on the selected features.
